# How to handle class imbalance with sklearn GroupKfold?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Sklearn has StratifiedKFold, but doesn't appear to have stratified GroupKFold. Does anyone have a good workflow for class imbalance in grouped data?

Answer (score 1):

The sklearn project did not yet include a stratified GroupKFold to their main branch.
However, there is a specific branch waiting to be merged to the master branch to include this exact feature.

You can find the branch at the following link:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/9413

Answer (score -1):

Sklearn has GroupKFlod http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html.
It may help you to create your own class.